# Grouping elements in HashMap into certain groups

Tags: java, hashmap, grouping

I have a set of elements stored in HashMap. So, I have to compare the values and if the values  retrieved are bigger than a certain value, it should be grouped into Group-n (where n = represent the n-th group).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GroupTag{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        myMap.put("0-1", 33);
        myMap.put("0-2", 29);
        myMap.put("0-3", 14);
        myMap.put("0-4", 8);
        myMap.put("1-2", 41);
        myMap.put("1-3", 15);
        myMap.put("1-4", 17);
        myMap.put("2-3", 1);
        myMap.put("2-4", 16);
        myMap.put("3-4", 18);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < 4; j++)
            {
                String testLine = i+"-"+j; 
                int itemA = myMap.get(testLine);
                boolean greaterThanAll = true;

                for(int k = j+1; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    String newLine = j+"-"+k;
                    int itemB = myMap.get(newLine);

                    if(itemA <= itemB)
                    {       
                        //Condition: e.g IF and ONLY IF all myMap.get(0-1)>than myMap.get(1-2), 
                        //myMap.get(1-3),myMap.get(1-n)
                        //THEN trigger an event to group ALL of myMap.get(1-n) to myMap.get(0-1)
                        //THEN remove all the values that satisfied the condition from the HashMap list
                        greaterThanAll = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }  

                if (greaterThanAll) 
                {
                    for(int m = j+1; m < 5; m++)
                    {
                         String removeLine = j+"-"+m;
                         //Group myMap.get(removeLine) to myMap.get(testLine)
                         //myMap.remove(removeLine);
                         System.out.println("Index " + removeLine + " : " +  myMap.get(removeLine));
                    }
                    //myMap.remove(testLine);
                    System.out.println("Main Index " + testLine + " : " +  myMap.get(testLine));
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}

Example of how the element are compared:
IF myMap.get("0-1")>myMap.get("1-n"): Grouped to Group 0 and REMOVE both values from list
IF myMap.get("0-2")>myMap.get("2-n"): Grouped to Group 1 and REMOVE both values from list
IF myMap.get("0-3")>myMap.get("3-n"): Grouped to Group 2 and REMOVE both values from list
THEN the loop goes on to compare myMap.get("1-2")>myMap.get("2-n") and so on..

Desired outcome:
Retrieve number of Groups: 2
Retrieve size of Group 0: 3
Retrieve elements in Group 1: [1, 16]
```

Basically, I just need a way to group/store a set of elements or data together?

EDIT: I posted the conditions. I thought it would be easier leaving the conditions out as I just wanted to group some elements together.

Comment: I don't really understand how you want to group the elements. Maybe you could clarify that.

Comment: Perhaps, I am complicating things here. Let me try to simply this..I have a list of elements stored in HashMap. All I need is a way to group a certain elements based on certain conditions. For example: Element 0, 5, 11, 12 should be grouped into Group-0; element 2, 4, 8, 14 goes into Group-1; element 3, 6, 13, 15 go to Group-2 and element 1, 7, 9, 14 go into Group-3.

Comment: Ok, but it would be nice to have an example for the condition. Your example doesn't really tell for me what the condition is.

Comment: Daniel, I've added the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, is building the expected string keys necessary for your requirements? Wouldn't it be easier iterating the map and looking whether the value is bigger than the number?

Maybe [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) is what you're looking for (until Java gets native Lambda expressions).

Comment: Actually, the values given are just mock values as the actual values are actually already stored in a HashMap. Then, the elements in the HashMap are iterated to check if myMap.get("0-1") is bigger than myMap.get("1-2"), myMap.get("1-3") and myMap.get("1-2"). If it is, then it will be grouped into Group-0. If not move on to myMap.get("0-2") to check if it is bigger than myMap.get("2-3") and myMap.get("2-4").

Comment: Well, I'm not a LambdaJ expert, but since it provides clojures you might be able to do that kind of comparison of one element against the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet(E, boolean, E, boolean)

You can use the subset() operation in TreeSet.

```
public NavigableSet<E> subSet(E fromElement,
                                      boolean fromInclusive,
                                      E toElement,
                                      boolean toInclusive)

    OR

public SortedSet<E> subSet(E fromElement,
                               E toElement)
```

Comment: Is it possible to show me a simple example how to call this method?